# Creating Login Item on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, authentication, process

I want to create a Login Item on Mac. [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG) provided by apple is really not helping.

I want a process to run in background as soon as user logs in and it should not be managed by LaunchD.

Can someone help we with details on how to create a login item? I have never done this before, so I am looking for step by step instructions with some sample code. I am targeting 10.6 & 10.7 OS X versions.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Please let me know if I can add more details to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this post](http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/02/creating-andor-removing-a-login-item/) has what you're looking for.  Why the launchd hate, though?  Achieving something like you're describing with a LaunchAgent plist would be dead simple.

Comment: I want to inject in Launchd process. If I create a launch agent from launchd, launchd will be its parent and then I cannot inject it launchd.

Answer (score 2):

The link provided by @lottscarson is not a good solution. With sandbox you can't use the method showed in that link. 
Take a look instead at "helper applications" and `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`.